# consistent textbooks on history of philosophy

Tags: history-of-philosophy

In my country there are several philosophy olympiads for school students and if you win one of them, you get the opportunity to enroll in any university in the country at the Faculty of Philosophy. the main problem is that my knowledge of the history of philosophy is rather mediocre, in the sense that I perfectly know the philosophical positions and how they relate to each other, but I have a bad idea who and when defended these positions. so I need to form a complete picture of who, when and how in the history of philosophy, adhered to their positions. Maybe there are some good consistent textbooks on this topic? Or maybe you know another way to study the history of philosophical ideas in detail?

Comment: Consistent? Anthony Kenny's history.

Comment: It is practically impossible for you to have acquired any real understanding philosophical positions without having at the same time acquired considerable knowledge of the history because the literature spends so much time discussing the history.

Comment: Old but good, [A History Of Philosophical Systems (edited by Ferm)](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.279384/page/n15/mode/2up), freely accessible. Goes up to the early 20th century, with different chapters written by different philosophers with special expertise on historical figures they are writing about. A useful supplement to [Kenny's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_New_History_of_Western_Philosophy) more recent but single perspective.

Comment: great books, thank you all!